# How to electronically sample speaker output

Tags: arduino, signal, embedded, speakers, microphone

I have a device which, under normal conditions, is connected to a 16 Ohm 0.25W speaker via two terminal blocks. When the speaker is connected it enables the device to play a song or other tone when events happen etc.

[image: An example wiring of the device]

From my understanding, the ground is a floating ground, when the device wishes to play a tone it will create a PWM that pulls the ground low and plays the tone. The device varies the volume by varying how strongly the ground pulls low, at a normal operating level the device pulls down to 8V. At maximum volume the device pulls all the way down to 0V.

I would like to replace the speaker with an equivalent resistor and sample the signal that runs through it so I have a waveform of the signal rather than sound.

I've been able to do this with an oscilloscope on a bench, but I would like to use something a bit cheaper/more portable. I've had a couple of ideas of how I could achieve this but I don't know how feasible/realistic they are.

1. Using a PCs built in microphone port
2. Using an ADC (either built into an Arduino or sampled by one) then sending the data over serial to construct into a waveform

For the first one I'm not sure how a PC microphone jack works, I'm not sure how much I need to scale the signal down by or how to wire it up. This one seems most ideal to me as I'd simply have to record a waveform from a microphone and have the waveform.

For the second one, I'm not sure how to scale the signal down to acceptable arduino levels. I've sampled single voltages with an Arduino before but never a waveform, though I assume I just sample as fast as possible for it's duration.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I've been getting nowhere with this for a long time.

Comment: Your drawing just connects a speaker to 12V DC supply which will break it. What kind of output stage your device has is up to the device. If it really outputs just PWM on the low side output then please verify it with scope by disconnecting the speaker. Anyway that is easy to interface with PC mic plug but you need device ground and maybe little attenuation. The exact circuit may vary but mic inputs are far from HiFi quality so bare minimum circuitry should suffice.

Comment: As far as the user of the device knows, they just connect a speaker to the ports and it makes sound, the circuitry to make sure the speaker doesn't break is on the ground side. As for the ground pulling low I have verified it on an oscilloscope, under normal operation it pulls down to 8V from 12V in a PWM. As for interfacing with a PC mic plug, could you point me in the direction of how to start?

Comment: If it is a class D amplifier, you will probably want to filter the output before sampling it with an ADC. Because you say "PWM"  I believe it IS a class D amplifier. First idea is to simply add a DC blocking cap and then low-pass filter it. Check with the oscilloscope to make sure it is a nice sine wave.